# Finding amicable numbers

Tags: ruby

I am working on the following exercise.

> Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
>   If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.
>
> Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

I am done running each segment of my solution independently. Here is what I have so far:

```
def is_amicable?(num)
    proper_factors = (1..(num/2)).select{ |n| num % n == 0}
    partner = proper_factors.inject(:+)

    if (1..(partner/2)).select{ |n| partner % n == 0}.inject(:+) == num
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

amicable = (1...10000).select{ |num| is_amicable?(num) }
sum = amicable.inject(:+)

p sum
```

My `is_amicable?` method works standalone, but when I run everything together, I get an error:

```
amicable_numbers.rb:5:in `is_amicable?': undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

From what I can gather, the issue springs up in this line:

```
amicable = (1...10000).select{ |num| is_amicable?(num) }
```

I don't see `/` as an undefined method on the line; that part works fine when I run it independently. That's the only line I can't get running independently, and it just gives the undefined/error.

Comment: Your description is contradictory. Can you run line 5 independently, or not?

Comment: start your range for amicable from `(2..10000)` it will work for you and returned `40284`  ;)

Comment: Yes I can run line 5.  Sorry that wasn't the line with problems I made the proper edit.  Thanks changing it to 2 works.  Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass 1 to `is_amicable?` you get this error. Trace through

```
num = 1
proper_factors = (1..(num/2)).select{ |n| num % n == 0} => []
partner = proper_factors.inject(:+) => nil
```

then you do

```
partner/2 => NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my code gets the wrong answer, even when I start at 2.  Any idea what I got wrong?

Comment: Yes. You have failed to consider all the requirements of the problem and the amicable array has the wrong number of elements which you then sum to produce the wrong answer. Inspect those elements and you will locate the problem.